# Answer .gif or .png image WebResourceResponse to shouldInterceptRequest

Tags: java, android, webview, png, gif

My function intercepts all the request done to the webview. Like load a page.

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view,
    String url) {...}
```

All the html, css and js files are answered correctly, but when I want to send a png or gif image as response, it does not work. They probably need special `MIME` types but I can't make it work.

Have to say that the images I want to send are received with a `HttpURLConnection` in an `InputStream` and converted to `String`, and saved in a folder; so when I need the image, I just take that file (a `String`) and convert it to `InputStream`.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageString.getBytes());
return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "UTF-8", is);
```

I tried with `image/gif`, `image/png` and nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're sending images, why are you setting the response content as `"text/html"`? An image is not html nor text. In the worst case, use `"application/octet-stream"` as if it is a generic file for download.

Comment: `WebResourceResponse("image/png", "binary", is);` should work for PNG image ok without any convertion (such as base64 suggested in some posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output stream needs to be `FileOutputStream`'s

You need to save the image in byte format, no encoding needed.

Keep in mind that the you need to keep the image file extention.
For example if you're downloading `image.png` and saving it as `image.tiff` it will not work.

This is how I would download an image:

```
URLConnection conn;

BufferedInputStream bistream = null;
BufferedOutputStream bostream = null;

boolean failed = false;

try
{
    conn = new URL("http://../image.png").openConnection();

    bistream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), 512);

    byte[] b = new byte[512];

    int len = -1;

    bostream = 
        new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(new File("/../image-downloaded.png")));

    while((len = bistream.read(b)) != -1)
    {
        bostream.write(b, 0, len);
    }
}
catch(Exception e) // poor practice, catch each exception separately.
{                   /* MalformedURLException -> IOException -> Exception */
    e.printStackTrace();

    failed = true;
}
finally
{
    if(bostream != null)
    {
        try
        {
            bostream.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                bostream.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    if(bistream != null)
    {
        try
        {
            bistream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

if(failed == false)
{
    //code
}
else
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: Your answer lead me to the correct answer:
I saved the image in base64 string and before sending it back to the webView with WebViewResource, I make it byte array and then Input Stream and format "image/png"

Comment: You can display the base64 in HTML, `<img src='data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,PLACE_BASE64_STRING_HERE'>`

Comment: I dont want to display it, I'm just answering to the requests as a normal server would do it.